# windows login with one time password

Tags: java, windows, authentication, active-directory, one-time-password

we have a central authentication server working with one time password.a customer wants to able to login their windows accounts with their tokens through our application.
how to integrate this server with windows?it must be with Active directory using our application or the windows itself can be connected to it? i did a lot of research but nothing good was there or i could not find them.
i'm looking for a tutorial kind of thing not a simple answer.i'm somehow completely in the dark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution i found for this problem was to add a Credential Provider (CP) for windows to change the authentication type to OTP and then use Raduis to connect it to the OTP server or any autentication server that you want.
to be more clear what thing you need for this is the Credential provider.its conditions depends on you. 
P.S : the CP i used was the PGina.